# how to use regex replace in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string, shown below

```
A123459922
```

I want to remove A and add B with Regex to the end of it. How can I do it using regex

```
Regex.Replace("A123459922","(\w{1})(\d*)");
```

I don't know exactly how can I remove the first character and Add 'B' to the end of it? to ended up something like this

```
123459922B
```

Comment: what's wrong with Substring() ?

Comment: Is `B` needed to be added only when there's an `A` in the beginning? Or always regardless?

Comment: I see , but just keen to know how regex can apply to this issue

Comment: So long as you don't care about any `A`, you can also use `string.Replace` which is faster but will also match any and all `A` even the ones you might want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'll use the same regex of your question.**

You could look at this (for more complex situations)

```
Regex.Replace("A123459922",@"(\w{1})(\d*)", m => m.Groups[2].Value + "B");
```

See the 3rd parameter of the `Replace` method. It is a `MatchEvaluator`, which receives a `Match` and returns the replacement string. The above expressions is equivalent to:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Regex.Replace("A123459922",@"(\w{1})(\d*)", Evaluator);
}

private static string Evaluator(Match m) {
    return m.Groups[2].Value + "B";
}
```

**You're basically saying**: I want to replace `the entire match` by `the 2nd group + the B character`

Comment: The question, while unclear, does mention "the first character". Shouldn't answers take this into account?

Answer (score 2):

According to your given input and output string example, you can do this simply with [`Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var newString = myString.Substring(1) + "B";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
Regex.Replace("A123459922", @"\w(.*)", "$1B");
```